# Есть ли альтернативы методу set() из класса VideoCapture, чтобы задать желаемый кадр?

Tags: java, android, opencv, компиляция, ffmpeg

**UPD3.** Я думаю, что вопрос будет закрываться, а мне придется отказаться от задуманной идеи, потому что пока работающего решения, как я понимаю не существует для android. Я попробовал еще из `javacv` граббер `FFMPEGFrameGrabber`, но он тоже не выставляет желаемый для меня кадр.
Последней попыткой попробую задать еще вопрос непосредственно на github opencv. Все что теперь хочется узнать - а есть ли какие-то альтернативы, чтобы выставлять просто желаемый кадр?

Я создаю `android`-приложение, где `opencv` обрабатывает поочередно каждый кадр видео через класс `VideoCapture`. Я проанализировал за несколько дней огромное количество сайтов в поисках своей проблемы, почему `Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS`, `Videoio.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` и другие константы возвращают всегда `0.0` в `android`. Некоторые говорят, что `opencv-android` возвращает только 2 значения ([ссылка на issue, где указан source-code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15547#issuecomment-721563922)), у других якобы просто не открывается видео.

Если я все правильно понял, то по факту `VideoCapture` извлекает метаданные видеофайла через `ffmpeg`, но на `android` оно как раз и не хочет работать по причине нехватки, как я думаю этого файла (`ffmpeg.so`). Да, я знаю, что opencv-android официально не поддерживает `ffmpeg`, но в интернете есть куча ответов на эту тему, и из них мне удалось найти только 1 более-менее полезную [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/254737/), как подключить opencv+ffmpeg (она уже устарела, поэтому не годится).

Опытным путем выяснил, что при подключении dll-библиотеки на компьютере:

`System.loadLibrary("opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll");`

будет возможность получать доступ к заветным константам `CAP_PROP_FPS` и`CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` и к методу `capture.set();`, который очень необходим сейчас в моем проекте...Если же не подключать эту библиотеку, то и возвращаться будет всегда 0.0.

Решил еще на крайняк проверить задумку, скачав библиотеку `com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever-core` - и действительно, она извлекает метаданные из видео в точности, как и программа `opencv` на компьютере с подключенной dll.

Было решено попробовать собрать свою `ffmpeg.so` библиотеку для android из исходников `ffmpeg`. К сожалению, я потерпел неудачу для сборки хотя бы под архитектуру `arm64-v8a`, ибо компилятор выдавал кучу ошибок по типу, что `#include stdlib.h` не найден. Банальные ошибки я сначала исправил, но потом пошли более сложные - я в `c`/`c++` особо не шарю.

Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Как ее решали? Возможно `JavaCV` предоставляет что-то похожее на метод `get()` и `set()` для `VideoCapture`? Если доступ к константам еще как-то можно решить через другие библиотеки, то доступ к методу `set` никаким другим способом пока что мне не удается решить для официальной `opencv`.

Есть действительно толковый туториал на сборку `ffmpeg` для `opencv` на android хотя 20-22 годов?! Правильный ли ход моих мыслей с файлом `ffmpeg.so`? Неужели никто в интернете не мог выложить собранные `*.so` файлы для android для архитектуры `arm64-v8a` и других? Ссылки на `Stack Overflow` можете не кидать - я почти все пересмотрел с этой темой.

Тестируется на:

```
Android: 12
MinSDK: 26
OC: Windows 10/Linux Ubuntu
OpenCV: 4.5.5
FFmpeg: 4.4
Ndk: 21.4.7075529 (использовал эту версию, так как обычно туториалы использовали некоторые файлы, которые в новой версии были удалены)
```

**UPD.**

Так, мне удалось раздобыть `*.so` файлы для разных архитектур, включая и `arm64-v8a`. Я попробовал подключить по типу:

`System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg"); // libffmpeg.so для arm64-v8a`

Но это все равно не решает мою проблему. Возможно требуется указать в файле `CMakeLists.txt` из sdk opencv-android что-то наподобие этого:

```
add_library(ffmpeg SHARED path-to-lib/libffmpeg.so)
set_target_properties(ffmpeg PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_link_libraries(ffmpeg)
```

Верно? Это ведь нужно для того, чтобы объединить opencv и `ffmpeg`? Если нет, то как можно добавить поддержку этих `*.so` файлов в самом opencv?

**UPD2.**

Одно что интересно, в консоли в какой-то из функций `opencv` отображается лог, где явно вписано значение для будущей константы `CAP_PROP_FPS` (то есть fps видео):

[image]

Но походу серверное API не хочет возвращать данное значение, непонятно почему так происходит (возможно из-за проблемы, которую я прикрепил в 1 ссылке про `source-code`).

Исходя из документации про метод `get` (блок `return` и `note`, где говорится про возврат 0.0), то как я понимаю в коде opencv-android явно не реализованы и прописаны логика для этих констант. Если это даже и так, то как быть с методом `set()`? Есть какое-то возможное решение?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем, кто помог...кхм, то есть спасибо самому себе! Ответа нет ни здесь, ни на официальном форуме `opencv`, что меня и забавляет. Но решение спустя 10 дней я таки нашел сам без единой помощи. Добиться корректной работы от официальной opencv мне не удалось, но непонятно каким чудом `FFMPEGFrameGrabber` из пакета `javacv` начал устанавливать желаемый кадр. Сначала не происходило ничего, пока я использовал видео с расширением `*.avi`, но как только выбрал  формат `*.mp4` - тогда и произошло чудо, и после него и начал выставляться кадр и для видео с расширением `*.avi`. Что касается констант, то этот граббер тоже позволяет получать метаданные из видео, там представлен как, например, `getFrameRate(...)` так и `setFrameRate(...)` и другие методы. Я уверен, что `opencv-android` мог бы выставлять желаемый кадр, как и `FFMPEGFrameGrabber`, но, вероятно, разработчики просто поленились добавить данную поддержку для версии `4.5.5`, на крайняк могли бы подсмотреть, как сделано в `javacv`.

Итого, вывод: на данный момент из официальной версии `opencv-android`, а это на текущий момент версия `4.5.5`, если вам нужно от видео получить только его разрешение (высота и ширина), то вам больше ничего не нужно будет устанавливать - пользуйтесь официальной `opencv`. Если же вам требуется извлечь метаданные из видео, установить текущий кадр, то вариантов может быть 2:

**1)** Независимые библиотеки от opencv, и занимают совсем немного места в вашем проекте: `MediaMetadataRetriever`/`FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` (советую вторую). Первая - встроенная библиотека, вторая поддерживает некоторые плюшки, в отличие от встроенной. Например, первая (встроенная) у меня не извлекала тоже никаких данных, а второй удалось извлечь метаданные из видео. Эти обертки также позволяют получать желаемый кадр, выставляя время, но полученные `Bitmap` не очень хорошего качества, да и вам для каждого видео придется писать собственный цикл, который будет рассчитывать время между каждым кадром, что не есть удобным.

**2)** Если же вам нужно более логичное и единое решение, то посмотрите в сторону `javacv`, там есть разные грабберы для перебора изображений и других полезных функций, что избавит вас от создания велосипеда. Но есть один момент - иерархия классов немного отличается от официальной opencv, поэтому придется постараться, чтобы переписать свой код, если он раньше был написан с официальной opencv, соответственно и типы данных будут отличаться (например для `javacv` существует своя собственная матрица `Mat`). Одним из преимуществ есть еще то, что вы можете поставить официальный `opencv` через `Gradle` из репозитория `javacv`, просто прописав зависимости. Но я в общем не стал уже переезжать на этот пакет, ибо официальный opencv мне показался более удобным, да и переписывать код не хочется.

Итого я пока что отказался от того, чтобы выставлять желаемый кадр (может в будущем таки рассмотрю эту идею, если в официальной opencv не добавят функционал), но для проекта использую `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` вместе с официальной `opencv`.